# How scared are you of snakes?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, prepositional-phrases, complements

Do you think that it is grammatically correct to ask questions by leaving adjective complements alone?

> How happy are you **about the exam results**?
>
> How disappointed were you **with my last behaviour**?
>
> How scared are you **of snakes**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving ... alone"?  Those are grammatical questions.

Comment: "About the exam results", "with my last behaviour", "of snakes" are adjective complements there and they are alone in those questions. However, the third one seems to be very weird because of "of snakes". 
We can't ask a question like "Which book did you buy of Stephen Hawking" but how can we ask the third question? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: What do you mean by "alone"? Your Stephen Hawking question is not an analogue.

Comment: You are scared of snakes. "Of snakes" is not alone now because it has its own adjective next to itself. They are together. However, in the question forms, adjective complements are far away from their adjectives.

Comment: OK.  I see what you mean. Is it possible to separate the complement from the adjective? Yes it is idiomatic to separate the complement from the adjective.  *She was scared as she walked barefoot along the beach of getting stung by a stranded jellyfish.*   That separation might be considered preferable to *She was scared of getting stung by a stranded jellyfish as she walked barefoot along the beach.*

Comment: It would probably be best to say *As she walked barefoot along the beach she was scared of getting stung by a stranded jellyfish.*  That is the simplest to parse, IMO.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo But is there any need to do that in your example? 
"She was scared of getting stung by a stranded jellyfish as she walked barefoot along the beach" seems to be better?

Comment: In such a construction the concluding *as*-clause could be understood to apply to the jellyfish (or whatever noun is in that position, *mutatis mutandis*), which can be disorienting, confusing, or comical: a female jellyfish walking barefoot.  Hence the reordering to put the *as*-clause in initial position, where it is adjacent to the subject it modifies and keeps intact what is predicated of the subject, *scared of getting stung by a stranded jellyfish*.

Comment: **He was knocked over by a bank-robber as he exited the bank.**.   Who was leaving the bank, the robber or the victim?

Comment: Of course "the victim". Saying "the robber" has no meaning. 
He was knocked over by a bank robber.
When? As the victim left the bank. 
If you say: "As the bank robber left the bank", it seems like there was one more bank-robber or that action was well-organized, or something else. It doesn't make sense to me. 
Your money can be stolen as you leave somewhere.
But how can your money be stolen as the thief leave somewhere? It seems weird maybe there can be some contexts that action can fit in, but I don't like that way.

Comment: Both scenarios are  plausible. The robber could easily have been fleeing the bank. In fact it's more likely that the robber would be running out of the bank in a hurry than running into it.  **knocked over** means "to fall to the ground because you've been jostled or bumped into".